# Converting Unicode to nsstring

Tags: ios, unicode

I am writing a code that will convert the Unicode to tibetan string. Strangely the code give right conversion on some Unicode while give null while converting Unicode to `NSString` in iOS using Objective-C.

My unicode is

```
cellName = "\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0d";
cellSubtitle = "\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f62\U0f72\U0f42\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f60\U0f51\U0f74\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f66\U0fa1\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f40\U0fb1\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f61\U0f74\U0f63\U0f0b\U0f42\U0fb2\U0f74\U0f0d \U0f66\U0f9f\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f58\U0f44\U0f60\U0f0b\U0f62\U0f72\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f90\U0f7c\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f42\U0f66\U0f74\U0f58\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f44\U0f0c\U0f0d \U0f56\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f56\U0f74\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f42\U0f59\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f62\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f5e\U0f72\U0f0d \U0f66\U0fa8\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f58\U0f51\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f41\U0f58\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f92\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f51\U0fb2\U0f74\U0f42\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f45\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f7c\U0f0d  \U0f0d";
```

and the text conversion is

```
cellName = "བོད།";
cellSubtitle = "བོད་རིགས་འདུས་སྡོད་ཀྱི་ཡུལ་གྲུ། སྟོད་མངའ་རིས་སྐོར་གསུམ་དང༌། བར་དབུས་གཙང་རུ་བཞི། སྨད་མདོ་ཁམས་སྒང་དྲུག་བཅས་སོ།  །";
```

for the unicode

```
cellName = "\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d";
cellSubtitle = "(\U0f62\U0f92\U0fb1\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f5a\U0f72\U0f42) \U0f21  \U0f46\U0f7a\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f63\U0fa1\U0f7c\U0f42\U0f0b\U0f5f\U0fb3\U0f0d \U0f56\U0f7c\U0f44\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f5a\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f62\U0f92\U0fb1\U0f0b\U0f41\U0fb1\U0f7c\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f7c\U0f42\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f9f\U0f7c\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f9f\U0f7c\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f60\U0f47\U0f7c\U0f42\U0f0b\U0f42\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f66\U0f92\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f53\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f49\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f44\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f59\U0f58\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f5f\U0f72\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f58\U0f7a\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f7c\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f4f\U0f7a\U0f0d  \n   \U0f51\U0f54\U0f7a\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f53\U0f0d \U0f41\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f5e\U0f72\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f46\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f51\U0f40\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f61\U0f7c\U0f63\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f0b\U0f5e\U0f7a\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f9f\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f74\U0f0d    \n2. \U0f53\U0f0b\U0f5a\U0f7c\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f42\U0f5e\U0f7c\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f7c\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f4f\U0f7a\U0f0d  \n   \U0f51\U0f54\U0f7a\U0f62\U0f0b\U0f53\U0f0d \U0f53\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f53\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f55\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f44\U0f74\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f74\U0f66\U0f0d \U0f55\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f53\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f56\U0fb1\U0f72\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f0d \U0f56\U0f74\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f0b\U0f5e\U0f7a\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f9f\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f74\U0f0d3. \U0f51\U0f58\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f60\U0f58\U0f0b\U0f5e\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f60\U0f72\U0f0b\U0f51\U0f7c\U0f53\U0f0b\U0f4f\U0f7a\U0f0d \U0f66\U0f7a\U0f58\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f49\U0f58\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f56\U0fb3\U0f7c\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f0d \U0f40\U0fb3\U0f51\U0f0b\U0f46\U0f74\U0f44\U0f0b\U0f5e\U0f7a\U0f66\U0f0b\U0f54\U0f0b\U0f63\U0f9f\U0f0b\U0f56\U0f74\U0f0d";
```

it gives me null value

And I am using this code for the conversion

```
NSData *data2 = [stringJoinedByNewLines2  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *decodevalue2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data2 encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Objective-C `NSString`s must be in the form `@"The string"`. You don't have the `@` in the code you posted.

Comment: @rmaddy stringJoinedByNewLines2 is an NSString type  so i don't have to but did as you said and it will print the stringJoinedByNewLines2 as the output ,

Comment: Perhaps there are one or more invalid characters in your string? Either actual non-7-bit-clean characters in the string literal, or invalid escaped unicode chars.

Comment: @Ben Zotto how to find that one and whats the solution.And why some part are still converting while the other it didn't ..Thanks for the reply

Comment: i realize that the unicode that are not converted has \n on the unicode  string does  that make a difference or not.

Comment: Why are you using `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding` after you created the `NSData` with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

Comment: if i use the NSUTF8StringEncoding at the place of NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding than it gives me the same unicode not tibetan string  font...I noticed that the one that are able to converted into string doesn't have the \n in the unicode,So what would you say on this